# Stata: Efficient way to replace numerical values with string values

Tags: stata

I have code that currently looks like this:

```
replace fname = "JACK" if id==103
replace lname = "MARTIN" if id==103

replace fname = "MICHAEL" if id==104
replace lname = "JOHNSON" if id==104
```

And it goes on for multiple pages like this, replacing an ID name with a first and last name string.  I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this en masse, perhaps by using the recode command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will echo the other answers that suggest a `merge` is the best way to do this.

But if you absolutely must code the lines item-wise (again, messy) you can generate a long list ("pages") of `replace` commands by using MS Excel to "help" you write the code. Here is a picture of your Excel sheet with one example, showing the MS Excel formula:

```
        columns:
          A         B      C     D
row: 1  last      first    id   code
     2  MARTIN    JACK    103   ="replace fname=^"&B2&"^ if id=="&C2
```

You type that in, make sure it looks like Stata code when the formula calculates (aside from the carets), and copy the formula in column D down to the end of your list. Then copy the whole block of Stata code in column D generated by the formulas into your do-file, and do a find and replace (be careful here if you are using the caret elsewhere for mathematical uses!!) for all ^ to be replaced with ", which will end up generating proper Stata syntax.

(This is truly a brute force way of doing this, and is less dynamic in the case that there are subsequent changes to your generation list. All--apologies in advance for answering a question here advocating use of Excel :) )

Answer (score 0):

Create an associative array of ids vs Fname,Lname

```
103 => JACK,MARTIN
104 => MICHAEL,JOHNSON
...
```

Replace 
id   => hash{id}  ( fname & lname )

The efficiency of doing this will be taken care by the programming language used

Comment: How do you create 'associative arrays' in Stata?  I've never seen this syntax.

Comment: The principle is good. Note that this is not, and is not presented as, any kind of Stata syntax.

Comment: The principle works efficiently only if you have a vectorized `paste` function to concatenate without looping. Can't remember if Stata does that -- it's not in `h string_functions`. All of this, of course, is to escape the good "dictionary" strategy (Nick's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain where the strings you want to add come from, but what is generally the best technique is explained at

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/group-characteristics-for-subsets/index.html

Comment: I'm not comfortable with putting it as a separate file-- it increases the likelihood of error with colleagues.  Do you know how to implement Ram's strategy?

Comment: A merge process is probably the quickest solution. You can always save and provide the merged data files for your colleagues nullifying the need for them to repeat this.

Comment: I don't see how using a separate file is any more error-prone than typing in the strings directly. Either way, this is exactly @Ram's strategy.